# Ruby on Rails operator logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, percentage

I'm trying to perform a calculation but can't get the required results. I am using three attributes:

`current_user.budget_income_tariff_rate` 1.52%

`current_user.economy_imports` 361,870,000,000

`current_user.economy_exports` 306,930,000,000

so basically I want to get `1.52% of 668,800,000,000`which should be `10,165,760,000`

I am unsure which method to use

`current_user.budget_income_tariff_rate * current_user.economy_imports + current_user.economy_exports / 100` doesn't work

`current_user.economy_imports + current_user.economy_exports * current_user.budget_income_tariff_rate` works but when I try to divide it by 100

`current_user.economy_imports + current_user.economy_exports * current_user.budget_income_tariff_rate / 100` the result is not correct.

I am sure the order of where the + * and / signs are placed is causing the problem. Does anyone know the correct calculation to use to get the required result?

Comment: That's what parentheses can be used for, enforcing order of operations. Placement is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

`<%= (current_user.economy_imports + current_user.economy_exports) * current_user.budget_income_tariff_rate / 100  %>`